# MySQL Error: 1064 (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

MySQL Error: 1064 (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1)
Session halted.

```
$sql =  "INSERT INTO ". GALLERY_MASTER
            .   "(gallery_title,gallery_code, gallery_images,gallerycat_id, gallery_description,gallery_status) "
            .   " VALUES ( "
            .   " '".   $post['gallery_title']              .       "', " 
            .   " '".   $post['gallery_code']               .       "', " 
            .   " '".   $file                           .       "', " 
            .   " '".   $post['gallery_cat_id']         .       "', "
            .   " '".   $post['gallery_description']        .       "', " 
            .   " '".   $post['gallery_status']         .       "', " 
            .   " )";
```

Invalid SQL:

```
INSERT INTO 
GALLERY_MASTER(gallery_title,gallery_code, gallery_images,gallerycat_id, gallery_description,gallery_status) 

VALUES ( 'image1', '021', '201411050700381463949438_img3.jpg', '4', '', '1', )
```

Comment: Remove the last , before the )

Comment: @Niraj7878 format the code before you post it, tag it appropriately to your DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, the problem is the additional comma in the end before the closing parentheses

```
Invalid SQL: INSERT INTO GALLERY_MASTER(gallery_title,gallery_code, gallery_images,gallerycat_id, gallery_description,gallery_status)

VALUES ( 'image1', '021', '201411050700381463949438_img3.jpg', '4', '', '1', )
---------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

You need to remove it using the below code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ". GALLERY_MASTER . "(gallery_title,gallery_code, gallery_images,gallerycat_id, gallery_description,gallery_status) " . " VALUES ( " . " '". $post['gallery_title'] . "', " . " '". $post['gallery_code'] . "', " . " '". $file . "', " . " '". $post['gallery_cat_id'] . "', " . " '". $post['gallery_description'] . "', " . " '". $post['gallery_status'] . "' " . " )";
```

Answer (score 0):

You had an additional `,` in the end of query.

Copy this code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO " . GALLERY_MASTER . "(gallery_title,gallery_code, gallery_images,gallerycat_id, gallery_description,gallery_status) " . " VALUES ( " . " '" . $post['gallery_title'] . "', " . " '" . $post['gallery_code'] . "', " . " '" . $file . "', " . " '" . $post['gallery_cat_id'] . "', " . " '" . $post['gallery_description'] . "', " . " '" . $post['gallery_status'] . "' " . " )";
```